# Case Number duplicates found for case insert in Test Class

Tags: case, failing-tests, test-setup

I faced a weird scenario today. I have a `@testSetup` method for inserting my case records and then used another method to query those case records to fetch `CaseNumber` field and pass it to a JSON String for Rest API.

When i insert the test records in my `@testSetup`, the query results for 2 case records fetched the same CaseNumber.

Example:

```
@isTest
public class someClass_Test {

    @testSetup
    public static void setup() {

        // code for inserting account & custom settings data 

        // inserting Case
        Case newCase1 = new Case(External_System_Reference_Id__c = 'C-002002002002',Origin = 'QAC Website',RecordTypeId = caseRTId,
                                Type = 'Service Request',Sub_Type_1__c = 'General',Sub_Type_2__c = 'Business',Status = 'Open',
                                Subject = 'to be decided',Description = 'some desc',Justification__c = 'must give',Authority_Status__c = 'Approved',
                                AccountId = myAccount.Id,Consultants_Name__c = 'abcd',Consultant_Email__c = 'test@test.com',Consultant_Phone__c = '28213812',
                                PNR_number__c = '4545451',Old_PNR_Number__c = '1021512',Passenger_Name__c = 'TestUser',Regions__c = 'DOM'); 
        insert newCase1;

        Case newCase2 = new Case(External_System_Reference_Id__c = 'C-002002002003',Origin = 'QAC Website',RecordTypeId = caseRTId,
                                Type = 'Service Request',Sub_Type_1__c = 'General',Sub_Type_2__c = 'Business',Status = 'Open',
                                Subject = 'to be decided',Description = 'some desc',Justification__c = 'must give',Authority_Status__c = 'Approved',
                                AccountId = myAccount.Id,Consultants_Name__c = 'abcd',Consultant_Email__c = 'test2@test.com',Consultant_Phone__c = '28213813',
                                PNR_number__c = '4545452',Old_PNR_Number__c = '1021512',Passenger_Name__c = 'TestUser',Regions__c = 'DOM');   
        insert newCase2;
    }

    @isTest
    public static void CaseUpdation()
    {
        Set<String> eachCaseNums = new Set<String>();

        for(Case eachCase : [Select Id,CaseNumber from Case]){
            system.debug('each case no:**'+eachCase.CaseNumber);
            eachCaseNums.add(eachCase.CaseNumber);
        }
        system.debug('case nums**'+eachCaseNums);
    }
}
```

Debug that I got:
In This image, you can see ID is unique but Case number duplicated.

[image: Case number duplicate]

**ANSWER / UPDATED**

I added this ,

```
list<Case> myCases = new list<Case>();
myCases.add(newCase1);
myCases.add(newCase2);
insert myCases;
```

I fixed this using `list<Case>` and inserted it. There i didn't find any duplicates on `CaseNumber`.
But I want to know why is this happening and what difference it had on `list<Case>` and each record insert.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue for auto numbers and seems no fix will be provided for this.

As mentioned in [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XFyAAM) link, salesforce says:

> We do not make any assurances on our autonumber scheme in test
>   context.